# How to call Utility Component from Main Component in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have one Utility Component named RuleComponent.js. where all the logics defiend to process rules. it is connected to Redux store to fetch data of UI elements and process rules on that.
Now I have different Component Main.js . Here I have render method where all UI elements defined . Now for every onchange event I want to call RuleComponent checkRule function to apply rule on particular element and based on result I should handle Error/Warning in Main Component.

I tried 2 approach . but both have some limitation.

1) Make RuleComponet as parent Component and Main.js as Child Component.
But problem with this approach is I want Rule Component as Utility Component. dont want Main Component fully depended to RuleComponent.

RuleComponent.js

```
render(){
        return(
            <div>
                Rule Component
                <Main checkRules={this.checkRules} setRuleDefination={this.setRuleDefination}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

2) Make RuleComponent as Child component of Main Component.
Now problem with this approach is for every change in Main Component  need to call child Component checkRule method and expect from them to send Rules final result so Main component can use them to show error/warning.

Comment: Have you tried making your "Utility Component" a collection of utility functions instead? Import the functions that are checking/setting rules and pass the results on to your Main component.

Comment: But I need Utility Component have Redux access.

Comment: Can your Main component not just dispatch the actions for the utility computations directly? Presumably they can set some app state values that are read back into the Main component. It isn't clear why you need a completely separate component just to run some utility computations. If you need two components then you'll need to loft some component state to a common ancestor instead of trying to make one or the other a parent to the other.